# Java Serialised object vs Non serialised object

Tags: java, serialization

1) Can a non-serialised java object be sent over the network to be executed by another JVM or stored in local file storage to get the data restored?
2) What is the difference between serialising and storing the java object vs storing the java object without serialising it?

Comment: Storing an object in a file or database or sending an object over the network implies serialization. Maybe not Java's ObjectOutputStream brand of serialization, but some form of serialization (XML, JSON, ORM, Protobuf, etc)

Comment: Thanks Thio , to be more specific - can only java classes implementing serializable interface be sent over the network?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Serialization is a way to represent a java object as a series of bytes. Its just a format nothing more. 
A "build-in" java serialization is a class that provides an API for conversion of the java object to a series of bytes. That's it. Of course, deserialization is a "complementary" process that allows to convert this binary stream back to the object.

The serialization/deserialization itself has nothing to do with the "sending over the network" thing. Its just convenient to send a binary stream that can be created from the object with the serialization.

Even more, sometimes the built-in serialization is not an optimal way to get the binary stream, because sometimes the object can be converted by using less bytes.

So you can use you're custom protocol, provide your own customization for serialization (for example, [Externalizable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Externalizable.html))

or even use third party libraries like [Apache Avro](http://avro.apache.org/)

I think this effectively answers both of your questions:

1. You can turn the non-serialized object (I guess the one that doesn't implement "Serializable" interface) to the series of bytes (byte stream) by yourself if you want and then send it over the network, store in a binary file, whatsoever.
   Of course you'll have to understand how to read this binary format for converting back.
2. Since serialization is just a protocol of conversion and not a "storage related thing", the answer is obvious.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mark - crystal clear :) How are the objects (ones that are not marked with serialisable interface) stored in heap space? Is it in binary format too? Can't these fetched and sent as is to another jvm or state be stored in DB using the representation of object in heap space? Does the object representation on heap differ for object marked with serializable vs non-serializable. Sorry , if these questions have to be part of another thread.

Comment: Objects when created with a 'new'/by reflection are stored in heap regardless the serializable interface. The fact that the object implements Serializable just makes possible to turn it to the byte stream with the help of the built-in serialization APIs (ObjectOutputStream) and later on perform a deserialization. That's all. Once you have an object represented as a series of bytes you can do whatever you want with these bytes - load to db, store in FileSystem, send you your friend in e-mail - whatever. But it has nothing to do with serialization. Its networking - a different story :)

Comment: Thanks Mark! What is the format of object stored in the heap? Cant this image be loaded into heap space of another jvm and used directly?

Comment: I think its internal to Java and might vary between JVMs. You can get a dump and analyze but for what? In order to load the object you should call 'new'/reflection or use deserialization. Of course the Target class should exist in that 'another JVM' you're talking about

Comment: Sorry , I was assuming that data is stored in heap in terms of bytes. I was thinking if the data is already stored in heap in terms of bytes , why should there be a special indicator and a process in order to transform it to bytes. Since you have mentioned that java objects can only be created by means of deserialization , I assume Apache Avro and Externalizable internally use serialization api provided by core java libraries (ObjectOutputStream) in order to support serialization / deserialization. Am I correct?

Comment: Externalizable is basically the same as serializable but it provides more 'fine-grained' control of what should be serialized and how. I don't really know how apache Avro works

Comment: @PunterVicky "Cant this image be loaded into heap space of another jvm and used directly?": there are major problems also beyond class resolution, for example reference resolution and representation of primitives. It is much more simpler (and flexible) to use some kind of serialization.

Answer (score 1):

In short, you don't store a non-serialized object in java. So I would say no to both questions.

Edit: ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream can write primitives as well as serializable objects, if that's what you are using.

Comment: Thanks Rogue. Will java throw an exception if non-serialised object is transferred over the network / stored in DB? What prevents java from storing an object that is not implementing "serializable" interface?

Comment: Yes, you will get [NotSerializableException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/NotSerializableException.html) in the target VM. What prevents a non-serializable object from being serialized is that it has no method to serialize the object, so it does not know what to write.

Answer (score 1):

> 1) Can a non-serialised java object be sent over the network to be
>   executed by another JVM or stored in local file storage to get the
>   data restored?

An object is marshalled using ObjectOutputStream to be sent over the wire. Serialization is a Java standard way of storing the state of an object. You can devise your own of doing the same but there is no point re-inventing the wheel unless you see a big problem in the standard way.

> 2) What is the difference between serialising and storing the java
>   object vs storing the java object without serialising it?

Serialization stores the state of the object using ObjectOuputStream and can de de-serialized using ObjectInputStream. Serialized object can be saved to a file or can be sent over the network. Serialization is the standard way to achieve all this. But you can always invent your ways to do so if you really have a point to.

Comment: "Serialization is a Java standard way of storing the state of an object". Well, for long-term persistence they seem to offer a second XML-based format.

Comment: @Thilo XML format is not defined by Java it is defined by W3C. Java surely has support for objects to xml and vice versa transformation through frameworks such as JAXB.

Comment: "XML format is not defined by Java it is defined by W3C". Really? java.beans.XMLEncoder looks like part of the JDK to me.

Comment: That's like saying "the Java language is defined by the Unicode consortium", just because we use UTF-8 for Java source code.

Comment: @Thilo Not exactly, java provides implementations which confirms to different specs. There are lot of protocols implementation APIs available in java that does not mean that java belongs to those protocols consortiums.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of serialization is to store the state of objects in a self contained way that doesn't require raw memory references, run time state etc.  In other words, objects can be represented as a string of bits that can be stored on disk, sent over a network etc.