# Data Exchange Formats and Java Seralization

Tags: java, web-services, serialization, ejb, rmi

A number of very useful answers posted in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19074867/java-serialised-object-vs-non-serialised-object) helped clear my questions around serialization. From the responses I understand that it is just a means to persist and re-create data in a jvm.So serialization is used for recreating a java object from byte stream. However data could be transferred by means of XML / JSON or via any other data format. So could this be called as serialization? I assume that the difference is that the relevant java libraries would re-create the object using byte stream / xml data / json data etc based on the format of data passed. In case of communication between 2 java based systems, I assume bytestream would be useful where as in case of communication between 2 systems working in different technologies other standard data formats will be used. In case of EJBs / Java RMI , I assume the objects that are transferred between client and server must be serialised as I assume java would be using standard serialization apis to deserialize the objects. Are all these listed above correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wiki sums it up well,

```
In computer science, in the context of data storage and transmission, 
serialization is the process of translating data structures or 
object state into a format that can be stored
```

So your first question

*However data could be transferred by means of XML / JSON or via any other data format. So could this be called as serialization?*

Yes absolutely. Any format you like, as long as its able to be stored.

Question two:

*In case of communication between 2 java based systems, I assume bytestream would be useful where as in case of communication between 2 systems working in different technologies other standard data formats will be used.*

Actually Java's built in serialization tends to be only used when its largely invisible to the user and when speed doesn't matter. For example some distributed products might send objects from one node to another using java serialization. For any kind of web service, even from a JVM backed service to another, some kind of friendly format like JSON or XML is far more common. For any product where speed was important or payload size must be as small as possible, they wouldn't use java's serialization but likely some priority binary format.

Protocols like [protobuf](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf/), [avro](http://avro.apache.org/) and [thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) were designed to try and give you the best of both worlds. They're somewhat popular but far from universal.

You might also hear the term marshalling, as in a marshaller or marshalling an object. They basically mean the same thing, although in Java land its more common to hear marshalling when you're talking about a non binary format, and serialization when its binary.

Comment: Thanks Monkjack! So in case of EJB or Java RMI, should objects always be serialised? Do these frameworks depends on java internal serialisation capabilities using ObjectOutputStream?

Comment: I don't know too much about EJB or Java RMI but I'd imagine they use Java's internal serialization or something similar.